# Disconnect / replace subgraph edges with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph data model in which all nodes are connected to one or more :policy nodes.

At times I need to modify a sub-graph so that it replaces all relationships to an existing P:policy with relationships to a new P':policy. The general approach I have in mind is to identify a subset of vertexes V and edges E associated with the existing P:policy; create a new P':policy, create new relationships E' between V and P', and then delete existing relationships E.

I have a variable length query that identifies the relevant P, V and E; that query looks something like this:

```
MATCH p=(v {..})-[nodes*]->(policy:policy {..}) return policy as P, nodes(p) as V, relationships(p) as E
```

This works fine as a standalone query, but to complete the sub-graph update what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
MATCH p=(v {..})-[nodes*]->(policy:policy {..}) // find the sub-graph of interest
MERGE (P':policy {..})-[]-(..)                  // create new policy P'
MERGE nodes(p)-[..]-(P')                        // setup new relationships from nodes(p) to new policy P'
DELETE relationships(p)                         // delete existing relationships(p)
```

I am a relative Cypher noob and it appears that I can't use nodes(p) and relationships(p) in my queries; wondering if anyone can provide advice how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nodes()` and `relationships()` return collections of nodes, this is why you cannot merge or delete them.

To get from a collection to single nodes or relationships, you can use [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/).
An example would be

```
WITH nodes(p) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as node
MERGE (node)-.....
```

or

```
WITH relationships(p) as rels
UNWIND rels as rel
DELETE rel
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use APOC Procedures, there are various refactoring procedures that can be used to clone a node and its relationships, as well as refactor the relationships, having the effect of redirecting them to the other node (but in reality making copies that point to the other node and deleting the originals)

See `apoc.refactor.cloneNodesWithRelationships()` and `apoc.refactor.to()` (or refactor.from() depending on which end of the relationships should be redirected to the new node).

You can use `call apoc.help('refactor')` to see all the refactoring procs once you have APOC installed.